# Output v$session (from oracle DB) in php code

Tags: php, oracle

I am using oracle db and I want to output the count of v$session in my php code. But when I run it, php reads it as a variable because of "$". Can anyone help me? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
        $sql = "select COUNT(*) SID from v$session";   
        $array = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($array);

        $row = oci_fetch_array($array);
        echo $row;
```

Error: 
      Notice: Undefined variable: session in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 12

Comment: you should use quotes like :  $sql = 'select COUNT(*) SID from v$session'; unstead of "test"

Answer (score 0):

you should change double quotes to single quotes like :

```
$sql = 'select COUNT(*) SID from v$session';
```

### **Here is some examples :**

**Strings with double quotes :**

```
<?php
$name = "ilyas";
 $age = 42
 echo "Hi, my name is $name and I am $age years old.";
?>
```

this will print :

> Hi, my name is ilyas and I am 42 years old.

**Strings with single quotes :**

```
<?php
 $name = 'ilyas';
 echo 'Hi, my name is $name mimo.';
?>
```

this will print :

> Hi, my name is $name mimo.